# Macbook Pro 2021: how to make globe key act like old FN (toggle between special and f-keys)?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, monterey

I'm upgrading from an old 2015 MBP (no touchbar) to a new 2021 MBP running Monterey 12.5.

On my old MBP, pressing fn key would toggle the top row from their default state (brightness, sound controls) to working like F1, F2, F3, etc.

How do I make the new MBP do this?

[image: screenshot]

If I leave check "Use F1, F2, etc..." then the top row is function keys by default.  If I leave it unchecked, then the globe/fn key doesn't do anything.

There is no option under "Press [globe] to..." for activate function keys!

FWIW, I don't use emojis, multiple inputs, or any of the other stuff the globe key is for - I use want to toggle f-keys.

Anyone figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Globe/Fn button acts exactly how it should, no matter what 'Press Globe to' is assigned to.

Test it set to Emoji & Symbols, with F1, F2 unchecked…
Press/release just the Globe, the Character picker opens.
Press Globe & F3 together, Mission Control opens.
Press just F3 & it will probably just beep, unless you have a specific function set up.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't think that's what I'm seeing.  When I have F1,F2 unchecked, I cannot get the globe key to activate the fn keys.  F5 always activate dictation, never sends the F5 key to my application.

Comment: Without knowing what you *are* seeing, there's little else I can offer. What are your results for each of the tests?

Comment: It does not matter what "press globe for" is set to.  Unless I have the F1, F2 box checked, pressing globe/fn will not activate the F-key function - just the special mac function like volume, etc.  I tried with each possible setting for the globe key.   However, if I check the F1, F2 box, then I only get f-keys - pressing globe/fn will not toggle the behavior to mac special functions like volume, etc.  I want to have normal mac keys most of the time, but f-keys when globe/fn is pressed , not have to check/uncheck the F1,F2 box every time I want to switch....

Comment: Try another account - see if something user-specific may be interfering.